# Converting multiple TSV files with same file name pattern (but different actual file names) into CSVs using Python

Tags: python, csv

There are multiple tsv files in a folder. I want to convert each tsv file into a csv file and merge all the csv files into one mega csv file.

```
customer_data = r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\CustomerData_20201030031520.tsv"
customer_data = pd.read_csv(customer_data,  sep='\t', low_memory=False)
```

This is how I get read and write to csv file. How can I do this for multiple tsv files efficiently rather than repeating this manually?

Notice the file name pattern? All the files would be in this pattern:

```
CustomerData_"year""month""day_number""random_digits".tsv
```

My objective is to merge all these multiple CSVs into a mega CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If the need is to merge a pack of similar-formatted files, there no need to actually load the data to memory, we can dump all files to one directly.

The snipped below will check the directory `path` for the pattern `pattern` and sort the resulting list by file names. After that, the list in the sorted order would be written in `out_file` file.

`outfile.write("\n")` is required is *.tsv file are not ended wit blank lines, otherwise it should be commented.

```
import os
import re

path = "c:\\temp\\1"
out_file = "c:\\temp\\1\\big_file.tsv"
pattern = re.compile("^.*_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{1,10}.\w{3}$")

matched_files = []

for f in os.listdir(path):
  if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f)):
    continue

  if not pattern.match(f):
    continue

  matched_files.append(f)

matched_files = sorted(matched_files)

with open(out_file, "w+") as outfile:
  for f in matched_files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), "r") as infile:
      outfile.writelines(infile.readlines())

    outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: pattern = re.compile("^.*_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{1,10}.\w{3}$")

===== What does this line mean/do exactly?

Comment: it matching only files like "anything_xxxxYYzzQQQQQQQQQQ.XXX" and processing only them